# How to run test classes one by one inside <test> tag using maven

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

I have below testng xml but its not working. Every time running by maven it strat execution on three browsers. I want to run all classes one by one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<parameter name="browser" value="${browser}" />
<parameter name="execution" value="${execution}" />

<test name="POC Test" preserve-order="true" thread-count="1" >
    <classes>
        <class name="com.testscript.OurPurposeTest" />
        <class name="com.testscript.ContactUsTest" />
        <!-- <class name="com.testscript.ChevronTest" /> -->
        <class name="com.testscript.SearchTest" />
        <class name="com.testscript.FinancialRegulatoryReportsTest" />
        <class name="com.testscript.CompanyHistoryTest" />
        <class name="com.testscript.HomePageTest" />
    </classes>
</test> <!-- POC Test -->
```

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${suiteXmlFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>
```

Comment: Did you try the "group-by-instances" option? http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods

Comment: That should not happen. preserve-order=true coupled with parallel=false should force TestNG to run the test classes in the order in which they were specified. Does your test class have any data driven test methods which are configured to run in parallel ? Can you please show us how your test class looks like as well ?